# Modelica smoothOrder of cubic polynomial

Tags: modelica, derivative

After reading the resources linked below, I have a question about Modelica annotation smoothOrder.

- https://www.claytex.com/tech-blog/automatically-getting-derivatives-of-a-function-in-dymola/
- https://specification.modelica.org/maint/3.5/annotations.html#modelica:smoothOrder

For a cubic polynomial the derivatives are:

1. derivative: quadratic function
2. derivative: linear function
3. derivative: constant value
4. derivative and higher: zero

What is the number to put into the annotation smoothOrder in this case?
Is it 3, or 4, or is it 99? There are no discontinuities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is a pure polynomial (not something like a piece-wise polynomial), the `smoothOrder` is actually infinite. The reason is - as you state in the question - that after some higher-order derivative all further derivatives will be zero. Therefore it does not get discontinuous.

As a result, the `smoothOrder` can be set to any high value. To finde a good value, lets consider the usage of the annotation: `smoothOrder` is used to determine how often a variable/equation can be differentiated. Differentiation of equations can be necessary due to the index reduction. How often a model needs to be differentiated is determined by the model's index (for which there are slightly different definitions). Generally the index describes, how often an equation needs to be differentiated to result in solvable equations. The index is usually not higher than three, for electrical applications it is usually not higher than one. Therefore, often `99` is often chosen as the index will not get higher than this...

Comment: Thanks, this already fixes the largest part. But of course I also do have a case where the polynomial is defined piecewise (2 or 3 pieces in my case): can I use spliceFunction to connect the pieces in a C99 smooth/continuous way?

Comment: Not sure what you refer to with `spliceFunction`, but generally it depends on the method how you "connect" the polynomials. From what I know, they are connected to be continuous up to the first differentiation - by settings the first derivative equal for the two joined polynomials. I don't think C99 makes a lot of sense usually...